# A simple question about normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppost we have a dataset as below: 
(Value,Frequency) pairs: (1,2), (2,4), (3,6), (4,8), (5,10)

Can we say that this data is normally distributed, or have a normal distribution for this dataset?

Comment: There seems to be no connection with any normal. The rlationship is linear.

Comment: They look like a straight line, not a bell curve ...

Comment: They don't look at all like a normal distribution, but it is just possible that these results could come from a sample from a normal distribution (very unlikely, I would think) - you could do a hypothesis test to see if it is so unlikely as to be "negligible".

Comment: I do agree with you, and it is what I think. But in Gaussian Naive Bayes, it is simply supposed that each feature has a gaussian distribution on our class. I am wondering how we can assume that without even observing the data and suppose that all the features can have a Gaussian distribution...

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to check is to plot this on a graph. For a normal distribution it should give you a curve with the middle almost perfect symmetry.